# How to redirect user to previous page after login in Angular Js and IonicFramework project

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working on an ionicframework project which allows user to view feeds and description but redirects the user to login page whenever the user clicks comment send button if the user is not logged in. How do I get the previous state when in the login page so that after login is successful the user is redirected to the previos page?

Comment: Check out: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicHistory/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify your run like this

```
run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function() {
        $rootScope.previousPage = location.pathname;
    });
}]);
```

When you get answer from your request you redirect to $rootScope.previousPage

Comment: This is a good option, but Ionic implements its own [history service](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicHistory/) that keeps track of views as the user navigates through an app.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$ionicHistory`. See documentation here 
http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/%24ionicHistory/

`backView()` will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use this: $ionicView.afterLeave:  The view has finished leaving and is no longer the active view.

so once they hit login, in the login controller just fire

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.afterLeave', function(){$state.go('some state')})
```

then you can statically or dynamically set the state it takes them to based on different variables. Say you save the name of the the last state they were on when the app closes, you can throw them right back in to where they left off. Read more here: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/