# Redirect user to application(route provider) if login is successful

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, redirect

I want to create a standalone login page and if I am successful then only I want to be redirected to route provider page and run the application.

I have tried making login page as default page (as shown in the code below) but that will not be a solution in long run just a work around for today.

Similar topics - 1. [Redirect if login is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37374299/redirect-if-login-is-correct)

2. [How to redirect user to previous page after login in Angular Js and IonicFramework project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31104931/how-to-redirect-user-to-previous-page-after-login-in-angular-js-and-ionicframewo)

I don't know how to use ionic framework, if you suggest that please explain as well

Here goes the code(route-provider.js)

```
  (function(){
       angular.module("EHS-App").config(function($routeProvider, 
              $locationProvider) 
        {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "../view/region_selection.html",
        controller : "regionSelectionController"
    })
    .when("/uploadData", {
        templateUrl : "../view/upload_data.html",
        controller : "uploadDataController"
    })
    .when("/LogOut", {
        templateUrl : "../view/LogOut.html",
        controller : "logoutController"

    })
    .when("/login", {
        templateUrl : "../view/login.html",
        controller : "loginController"

    })
    .when("/dashboard", {
        templateUrl : "../view/dashboard.html",
        controller : "dashboardController"

    })
     .otherwise({
    redirectTo:'/'
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

angular.module("EHS-App").run(function($rootScope) {
$rootScope.$on( "$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
    if(next.$$route.originalPath == "/"){

    } else if(next.$$route.originalPath == "/dashboard"){

    }
       });
       });
         }());
```

Home.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top"  > 
        <div class="container-fluid" >
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-
               toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" 
             aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
                        class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar">
                       </span> <span
                        class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">abcd</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown" uib-dropdown>
                        <a href="" id="overviews" class="dropdown-toggle" 
              uib-dropdown-toggle aria-haspopup="true" aria-
            expanded="false">
                            Overviews <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu aria-
                           labelledby="overviews">
                            <li><a href="#!abcd">abcd</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown" uib-dropdown>
                        <a href="" id="goals" class="dropdown-toggle" uib-
                dropdown-toggle aria-haspopup="true"
                        aria-expanded="false">Goals <span class="caret">
                  </span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu aria-
                            labelledby="goals">
                            <li><a href="#">Goal Builder</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Customize Goal</a></li>

                        </ul></li>
                    <li class="dropdown" uib-dropdown>
                        <a href="" id="measures" class="dropdown-toggle" 
                 uib-dropdown-toggle aria-haspopup="true"
                        aria-expanded="false">Measures <span class="caret">
                           </span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu aria-
               labelledby="measures">
                            <li><a href="#">Add new</a></li>
                        </ul></li>
                    <li class="dropdown" uib-dropdown>
                        <a href="" id="abcd" class="dropdown-toggle" uib-
            dropdown-toggle aria-haspopup="true"
                        aria-expanded="false">Forecasting <span 
                   class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu aria-
                  labelledby="abcd">
                            <li><a href="#">Create New</a></li>

                        </ul></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">Report</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Administration</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" data-ng-model = "Dropdown" 
                role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
                        aria-expanded="false">{{username}} <span 
                   class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">View Profile</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Change Password</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-header">More</li>
                            <li><a href="#!login" >login</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#!LogOut" type = "button" data-ng-
                click= "showAlert()">LogOut</a></li>

                        </ul></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </nav>
```

login.html

```
<div id="parent">  
  <div data-ng-show="error" class="alert alert-danger">{{error}}</div>
<form name="form" id="form_login" data-ng-submit="login()" role="form" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="container" ><br>
  <br>
  <br>

    <label><b><b>Username</b></b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" data-ng-
 model="username" required><br>
<span data-ng-show="form.username.$dirty && form.username.$error.required" 
 class="help-block">Username is required</span>
    <label><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" data-ng-
 model="password" name="psw" required><br>
    <span data-ng-show="form.password.$dirty && 
form.password.$error.required" class="help-block">Password is 
required</span>

    <button type="submit" data-ng-disabled="form.$invalid || dataLoading" 
data-ng-click="validUser()" class="btn btn-danger">Login</button><br>

    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Remember me<br>

    {{message}}
  </div>

  <div class="container" >
    <button type="button" data-ng-click="reset()" >RESET</button>

  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

login controller

```
angular.module("abcd-App").controller("loginController", 
function($scope,$timeout, $location, $http, $location, $window) {


    $scope.validUser = function(){
        if($scope.username != $scope.password)
            {$scope.message = "authentication unsuccessful, Please try 
  again!";}
        else
        {$scope.message = "authentication successful, You will now be 
     redirected in 3 seconds";
        $timeout(function() {
            $location.path('/home');
              }, 3000);
    }
    }



    $scope.reset = function(){


    $scope.username = "";
    $scope.password = "";
    };
});
```

Comment: Not clear what specific problem is

Comment: Problem statement mentioned in first few lines. I want a login page . This login page should be seperate from application. When login is successful, only then routeprovider should be called

Comment: That is the objective...not a specific problem related to acheving objective

Comment: Ok a specific problem :- How to redirect to route provider after a successful login.

Comment: Use `$location` service